# Laravel 5.6: Create database schema using migration

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I want to create several schemas to my database using migration. I have this code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSchemaAdministracion extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        DB::unprepared("CREATE SCHEMA `administracion`");
    }

    public function down()
    {
        DB::unprepared('DROP SCHEMA `administracion`');
    }
}
```

I tried this way but I got: Invalid schema name: `7 ERROR: No schema has been selected`.

Comment: Try something like `DB::getConnection()->statement('CREATE DATABASE :schema', ['schema' => 'administracion']);` maybe?

Comment: I don't think that it's a responsibility of a migration to create databases.

Comment: It'd also be faulty to assume the db user has privileges to create their own database.

Answer (score 2):

Try using DB::statement with DB::raw.

I tested this with Laravel 5.8. I guess it should work with earlier versions too.

```
\DB::statement(\DB::raw("CREATE SCHEMA administracion"));
```

You can then use it with the schema as prefix. Like this:

```
Schema::create('administracion.mytable', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    ...
});
```

Notice for rollback operation: consider that in postgres you cannot drop a schema if it has elements. You should remove them before removing the schema.

Answer (score -1):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAdministracionTable extends Migration
{

  public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('administracion', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('name');
      $table->string('airline');
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }


  public function down()
  {
    Schema::drop('administracion');
  }
}
```

Comment: That code creates a table, not a [schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html).